# animtion not working on page redirection in safari and IE 11

Tags: css, browser, safari, css-animations, internet-explorer-11

I have tried to show a loader animation on page redirection, the redirection was initiated via form submit. But the animation is not working in Safari and IE. Have tried CSS keyframe animation, GIF and video nothing works. GIF and video are not playing, it is just showing a static image. Facing this issue in Safari and IE11.

Comment: I don't know about IE but on safari, during the page loading, all the animations are blocked by the browser itself.

Comment: I suggest you to show your sample code. So that we can try to see what you are doing actually in your code. We can use it for testing with IE and other browsers to check the result.

Answer (score 0):

Try this [W3Schools example](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_loader.asp). It is working fine with IE 11 and other browsers.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
/* Center the loader */
#loader {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: -75px 0 0 -75px;
  border: 16px solid #f3f3f3;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top: 16px solid #3498db;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

/* Add animation to "page content" */
.animate-bottom {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-animation-name: animatebottom;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-name: animatebottom;
  animation-duration: 1s
}

@-webkit-keyframes animatebottom {
  from { bottom:-100px; opacity:0 } 
  to { bottom:0px; opacity:1 }
}

@keyframes animatebottom { 
  from{ bottom:-100px; opacity:0 } 
  to{ bottom:0; opacity:1 }
}

#myDiv {
  display: none;
  text-align: center;
}
</style>
</head>
<body onload="myFunction()" style="margin:0;">

<div id="loader"></div>

<div style="display:none;" id="myDiv" class="animate-bottom">
  <h2>Tada!</h2>
  <p>Some text in my newly loaded page..</p>
</div>

<script>
var myVar;

function myFunction() {
  myVar = setTimeout(showPage, 3000);
}

function showPage() {
  document.getElementById("loader").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("myDiv").style.display = "block";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Output in IE 11 browser:

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I want to show a loader during the redirection of page2 from page1. On clicking the form submit from the first page, will redirect the second page.

Comment: Then you can try to put this code on the page from where you are pressing the submit button. so loader will show after the user click the submit button and it will vanished when new page get load. There is no way to show the loader in between the redirection.